# Tips for more then one company using django system, with the same project

Tags: django, postgresql

I have this Django project, all my costumers will use them.. the same project, the same files. Only change the database.

What`s is the best way to do these?

Current I'm using, for each costumer, I create a folder in my apache server, create one sub-domain to manage them. But this take lot of time!

I'm using postgreSQL as database.

With these configuration, what's the best way to do these? Any ideas is welcome.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple solution:

Make one path for my project files, and for each sub-domais, I have wsgi file to select the `settings.py` correspondent of costumer.

In that case, each costumer has own settings.py

I take looking for django-tenant, but, in my case, I want to different database, not schemas.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

another way to consider could be to use [sites](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/) framework and a c[ustom database router](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/),

You could select the correct database based on the site that is being used.

Answer (score 0):

There is an application called [django-tenant-schemas](https://github.com/bernardopires/django-tenant-schemas) that would help you achieve this. It's also made for Postgres.